# php header expire every day at X

Tags: php, header

How can I set the document to expire every day at 2AM in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
header("Expires: " . date("D, j M Y", strtotime("now")) . " 02:00:00 GMT");
```

or

```
header("Expires: " . date("D, j M Y", strtotime("tomorrow")) . " 02:00:00 GMT");
```

Answer (score 1):

[php::header() resource](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

You will want to use:

```
//assuming getTimeUnitl2AM() returns time in seconds until 2am 
//if you need help implementing a function that returns 
//time until 2am ask 
$time = getTimeUntil2AM(); 
header("Expires: $time"); // set expiration time
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// 2AM today
$epoch = mktime(2,0,0,date('n'),date('j'),date('y')); 

// Go to tomorrow if current time > 2AM
$epoch += date('H') >= 2 ? 86400 : 0; 

// Send header with RFC 2822 formatted date
header('Expires: '.date('r', $epoch));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) to get the Unix timestamp at 2 AM and subtract that from the current time:

```
$diff = strtotime('2 AM') - time();
if ($diff < 0) $diff += 86400;
```

You can then use that difference for [*Cache-Control*](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9)’s *max-age*:

```
header('Cache-Control: max-age='.$diff);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the *Expires*-HTTP-Header (for an example, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)) with [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). You just need to specify the date.

```
header("Expires: " . date('D, d M Y') . " 02:00:00 GMT");
```

[date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Note, that this is GMT. You maybe want to set another timezone.